# default checkbox to unchecked query

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have set some checkboxes and when selected they will show hidden columns of a table so I can keep it condensed.

I can't seem to set the checkbox to be unchecked on load and not show the columns relating to the checkboxes, they're all visible and checkboxes all checked.

This is my jquery code

```
$("input:checkbox").attr("checked",true).click(function()
{
    var shcolumn="."+$(this).attr("name");
    $(shcolumn).toggle();
    
});
```

full html

```
    <form action="read.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="Value To Search"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Filter"><br><br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="DateofHatch" >Date of Hatch&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input type="checkbox" name="RingNumber" >Ring Number&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input type="checkbox" name="Article10Number" >Article 10 Number&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input type="checkbox" name="MicrochipNumber" >Microchip Number&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input type="checkbox" name="FlyingBird" >Flying Bird?&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="MinimumFlyingWeight" >Minimum Flying Weight &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="MaximumFlyingWeight" >Maximum Flying Weight&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input type="checkbox" name="DisplayBird" >Display Bird&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input type="checkbox" name="AnkletSize" >Anklet Size&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input type="checkbox" name="Deceased" >Deceased?&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input type="checkbox" name="DeceasedDate" >Deceased Date&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input type="checkbox" name="GeneralNotes" >General Notes&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$("input:checkbox").attr("checked",true).click(function()
{
    var shcolumn="."+$(this).attr("name");
    $(shcolumn).toggle();
    
});

</script>
```

Comment: *"I can't seem to set the checkbox to be unchecked on load"* -- well that's because you used `.attr("checked",true)`

Comment: What should I have used? If I change it to false it only shows the data if I uncheck the box. Sorry it may seem basic but I have no coding experience.

Comment: I think you should simply remove `.attr("checked",true)`. Please show some HTML so I can get a picture of what you're doing. Read: [mcve] and [edit] your question to add the necessary code.

Comment: Thank you, I've added some more. Essentially I have a table showing results from mysql database but I don't want to show all the columns straight away, I wanted the checkboxes so you tick the ones you want to show the columns but I want them unchecked and columns hidden on load. when I remove the code you suggested it stops working. Hope that helps.